# Integrate $x+y$ over the triangle with the vertices $(0,0),(1,0),(0,1)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

> Integrate $f(x,y) = x+y$ along the triangle with the vertices $(0,0),(1,0),(0,1)$

I have set $\gamma_{trinagle}=\gamma_1+\gamma_2+\gamma_3$ where:

$$\gamma_1(t)=(t,0), t\in[0,1]$$
$$\gamma_2(t)=(1-t,t), t\in[0,1]$$
$$\gamma_3(t)=(0,t), t\in[1,0]$$

so $$\int_{\gamma}f(x,y)ds=\int_{\gamma_1}f(x,y)ds+\int_{\gamma_2}f(x,y)ds+\int_{\gamma_3}f(x,y)ds=$$

$$=\int_{0}^{1}tdt+\int_{0}^{1}(1-t+t)\sqrt{2}dt-\int_{0}^{1}tdt=\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{2}-\frac{1}{2}=\sqrt{2}$$

But the answer in the book is $\sqrt{2}+1$ where did I get it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\gamma_3$ goes from $(0,0)$ to $(0,1)$, you need one from $(0,1)$ to $(0,0)$.

Comment: why? $\gamma_3(t)=(0,t), t\in[1,0]$

Comment: But it is not a vector field, why does the orientation matter?

Comment: $t\in [1,0]$ makes no sense.

Comment: Orientation matters in line integrals.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/595780/does-the-orientation-you-evaluate-line-integrals-matter

Comment: I'm not following that link.

Answer (score 1):

You titled this "Integrate x+ y over the triangle with vertices (0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1) and I at first, like the previous poster, thought you meant over the area of the triangle.  But if you mean a path integral, then then you also must state the **direction**.

Going around the triangle counter-clock-wise, the integral is from (0, 0) to (1,0), then from (1, 0) to (0, 1), and finally from (0, 1) TO (0, 0).

Going around the triangle clockwise, the integral is from (0, 0) to (0, 1), then from (0, 1) to (1, 0), and finally from (1, 0) to (0, 0).

Swapping the direction of a line integral changes to sign.